# What do you think about Lightning Experience usability?

Tags: lightning-experience

Lightning Experience has been available for more than a year now, and I wanted to have your opinion about it.

From my point of view, LX is a very beautiful user interface. Salesforce has done a good job on this part. But still, I wouldn't recommend it to my clients for the following 2 reasons:

- I find it extremely slow, even with a fast internet connection. Almost every client for whom I showed LX complained how slow it is.
- Sometime you can't open a new tab, and this, form my point of view, makes the UI truly Non Usable on a daily basis. If you can't open new tabs in your browser, how can you work on several items at the same time? Just try to click Setup on a new tab, it won't work, it is frustrating. Besides, when opening tab works, it loads the whole thing and you wait 4 or 5 seconds for a an opportunity or account detail page to load. Again, frustrating.

For these 2 reasons, I recommend to stay in Classic. It's not that compelling, but it works well and it's fast.

What do you think about Lightning Experience folks? Do you experience the sames problems as me?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this will be closed for being primarily opinion-based, but I pretty much echo your sentiments. I remember from Dreamforce last year that there were concerns about middle-click to open in new tab being almost entirely discarded in favor of chasing [the SPA design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) and JS framework crazes. I feel that Lightning was half-baked when it was released, and it hasn't yet matured to the point where my org can use it (and certainly not to the point where I can use it in my dev work).

Comment: Yes, SPA is actually a good idea, but for mobile apps not for desktop apps. Because you don't open a new tab in a mobile device when you're using Salesforce1 for example. Mobile experience is completely different from desktop experience and wanting to merge both into one app is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

You should look for winter 17 update .In winter 17 update the navigation's have changed back and definitely performance seems to be improvised .

[image]

The problems you described exists and folks have experienced and that really have slowed the adoption .

But with every release we have seen improvements as well and seems like in future salesforce is eventually get there just as it happened with scontrols and visualforce 6 years back .

We are in transition journey and hence you should start with a pilot program for very small amount of users in your organization and gather feedback .Depending on the feedback from users you can decide to adopt or stay with Aloha .Your users are your best to gather feedback and decide .

Comment: Thank you for this response. I'm looking forward for Winter17!

Comment: @mohit from where you found winter 17?
https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2016/08/salesforce-winter-17-sandbox-preview-instructions.html

This says we would get winter 17 in from mid sept

Comment: @pranay thats in prod . Release notes are getting released in couple days and gs0 org (pre release org) has been upgraded now .